# How to run your Shopify app without Ngrok?

Tags: localhost, shopify, shopify-app

I used Shopify CLI to set up my Laravel app, but I faced the request limit using Ngrok, is there a way to keep testing my app without paying Ngrok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloudflare Tunnel](http://cloudflare.com/products/tunnel/) in one of my apps. I use Laravel, I configured all the required commands to run via `package.json` file, so I just need to run yarn dev and it will run:

- `source .env`
- `php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8000`
- `cloudflared tunnel run your_tunnel_name_here`
- `NODE_ENV=development yarn watch`

You will have to make sure you configure Cloudflare to not have the cache to the URL you decided to use. Then you will have your app running via a free tunnel as before.

This is how my `package.json` looks like:

```json
{
    "name": "my_app_name_here",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "sh -c 'source .env; php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8000 & cloudflared tunnel your_tunnel_name_here & NODE_ENV=development yarn watch'",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production yarn production"
    },...
```